# Referencing a dynamic name in PowerQuery results in an error

Tags: excel, powerquery, m

I have created a new name (variable) in excel using the Name Manager which is called `fPath`. The value for the name is `=CELL("filename")`.

[image: Name (variable)]

I would like to reference this name as a parameter to the source within a function query. But, when I try to invoke the function within the `Power Query Editor`, I get an error that it wasn't able to find the name.

When the name refers to a cell within the sheet, this works perfectly but when a name is created without a reference to a cell, it is unable to find it.

Am I correct in assuming that what I'm trying to do is not possible?

**EDIT**:

Here's the code for for the Function Query where I have defined a parameter which is then used to dynamically get the source of the file.

[[image: query details]]

[image: Error Image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see this from Ken Puls

https://www.excelguru.ca/blog/2014/11/26/building-a-parameter-table-for-power-query/

Comment: I’m aware of this but sheets / tables can be deleted. I was looking for a solution that uses Names without having to add references in the sheets.

Comment: I would put the table on a Sheet then mark it very hidden, that way it cannot be deleted. Best work around , I have been using this for about 6 months

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
= Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="fPath"]}[Content]
```

Or:

```
= Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("C:\YourFile.xlsx"), null, true){[Item="fPath",Kind="DefinedName"]}[Data]
```

Comment: I've tried the first one already and it doesn't work - it results in the same error. I cannot use the 2nd one as it defeats the purpose. I'm trying to dynamically get the file path.